# Excel pivot table - MS access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have an Excel pivot table connected to an Access database.

When I click on the pivot table area, the new spreadsheet shows 28,000 lines, but the queries in database seem to generate 7,000 lines.

How do I find out the SQL that generates the pivot table? When I try (in Excel) Data > Connections > Properties, the Edit Query button is disable.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the data come through Powerpivot?

Comment: I do not know. The guy who created the spreadsheet does not work here anymore. How do I know if it comes from PowerPivot?

Comment: I beg your pardon. 
When I type File > Options in Excel, I see PowerPivot for Excel, but the power pivot does not appear in the Ribbon

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking Refresh All on the data tab.  Also you can set how Excel refreshed the data coming through the connection through Connections > Properties > Usage tab.